# Get data from .CDB file

Tags: cdb

i would like to get data from.cdb file. Is it possible to retrieve data from .cdb file without knowing keys names?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about [CDB constant database](http://cr.yp.to/cdb.html) files, the **cdbdump** program will dump all data in **cdbmake** format on standard output.

Comment: Where will this cdbdump come from ?

Comment: Follow the 'CDB constant database' link above, then go to the 'How to install cdb ' link on that page.